# What does "dish" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In this [article about male friendships](http://www.mensjournal.com/magazine/print-view/do-men-suck-at-friendship-20140422), there are two references to "dish":

> "Well, what do you have for me?" Dish, she meant – like maybe some of that marital strife.

and:

> "What do you got for me? Any dish?"

I'm a pretty confident non-native speaker, and I know it refers to neither food nor plates and bowls nor antennas. Nor [this sexist talk](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dish).

I'm pretty sure this is about gossip or something in that area but I couldn't find any sources.

Comment: Yes, gossip. See here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dish+the+dirt

Comment: @aps You should post that as an answer, so I can accept it. That source is spot-on! :)

Comment: Ok, I made it into an answer!

Comment: I add this link: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/dish

Comment: @Josh61 Wow. That's just brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means gossip. See [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dish+the+dirt).

Comment: It seems that verbs may be nouned.

Comment: That only seems fair, since you seem to have verbed _noun_ :)

Answer (score 1):

It means should be patter. We can replace patter.